# jquery onclick to get html and posting php via ajax freezing

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
var content = $(".highlight").click(function() {
    $(this).html();
}).get();

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "tosqltwo.php",
    data : {
        content : content
    }
});
```

This seems to be freezing my server though, any ideas on if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Your code is messed up. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The issue with your code is that the .get is doing nothing and your $.ajax is never called...A few examples of how to do this correct have already been posted.

Comment: I offered an edit to your question to clarify and format the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$(".highlight").click(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tosqltwo.php",
        data: {
            content: content
        },
        success: function(data){ 
            // success, data holds the output of tosqltwo.php
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // failed, check the textStatus and errorThrown to see why
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: how would I check if it was successful or not ?

Comment: you will need to use the `success` and `error` methods.. *updating answer*.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to pass a jQuery object `content` to the AJAX call. Also, what are you trying to do when you say `.get()`? You are not passing any parameters to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to do

```
$('.highlight').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
                type:           "POST",
                url:            "tosqltwo.php",
                data:            {content:$(this).html()}
            });
});
```